# Unable to get all my images in web application via fql.query

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I had this API that gives me all the images in my galleries. Now, when I'm using it outside of the Facebook applications, and just as web application, I getting an empty array.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo "$user<br>"; // gives me the uid
$user_albums_photos = $facebook->api(array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => 'SELECT src,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())'
));

 print_r($user_albums_photos); // Gives me an empty array, when it's a web application.
 $r_c = count($user_albums_photos);
 echo "<br>$r_c<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks fine and I am able to run it no problem when I provide a good user access token.  Lint your access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and see if it has the appropriate permissions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: well when i run the access token in the lint is show me i have all the right permissions like : user_photos , do i need more?

Comment: nope, are you able to run that query in the explorer as I can using a different app's token?

Comment: can it be , that when im using the api out side of facebook
i can get the user_photos permission ? when i query permissions im getting that user_photos permission is not granted.

Comment: are you able to run that query in the explorer?